# Regex matching for some selected dates

Tags: python, regex

I am writting a python program that should basically return True for some selected dates of any year i.e. dates can only be 1/1/XXXX or 4/1/XXXX or 7/1/XXXX or 10/1/XXXX.

I have written below code for this:

```
import re
date_value = '10/1/2018'
re.match("^[1,4,7,10]/1/[0-9]{4}$", date_value)
```

However, it is not working when i supply '10/1/2018' as date_value, but working for other dates.
Can someone please help me in finding issue here?

Comment: The `[]`instruction will match only one character, here you say: "match one of those thing: one, comma, four, comma, seven, comma, one, zero.

You need to use the `()` with pipes:  `(1|4|7|10)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match it using the pattern `r"^(1|4|7|10)/1/[0-9]{4}$"`. When you use `[1,4,7,10]`, it tries to match any of the chars `1,4,7,10`

```
>>> import re
>>> date_value = '10/1/2018'
>>> re.match(r"^(1|4|7|10)/1/[0-9]{4}$", date_value)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 9), match='10/1/2018'>
```